# Submitting Form in a popup window

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I know that this might seem like a duplicate, but i can't seem to figure this out. I am wanting to submit a form in HTML to a Popup window. when i hit the submit button, it returns a blank page. I want the pop up to display all of the input that one filled out one the form. I want to do it in JavaScript. This is my code here. I want it to output all of the information entered in the form, from the Personal Information fieldset and the personal choices fieldset. I want it to display as an unordered list.

Heres the Javascript that i have so far:

```
  <head>
  <title>My Form</title>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  function display() {
  dispWin = window.open('','NewWin', 
  'toolbar=no,status=no,width=300,height=200')

  message = "<ul><li>First Name:" + 
  document.mdForm.first_name.value;
  message += "<li>Last Name:" +  
  document.mdForm.the_lastname.value;
  message += "<li>Address:" + 
  document.mdForm.the_address.value;
  message += "</ul>";

  dispWin.document.write(message);
  }
  </script>
```

Heres the HTML:

```
  <body>
  <h1>My Form</h1>
  <form name="mdForm" method="post" action="">
  <fieldset>
  <legend>Personal Information</legend>
  <p><label class="question" for="first_name">What is your First name?              
  </label>
   <input type="text" id="first_name" name="first_name"
          placeholder="Enter your First name."
          size="50" required autofocus /></p>
    <p><label class="question" for="the_lastname">What is your Last name?  
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="the_lastname" name="the_lastname"
            placeholder="Enter your Last name."
            size="50" required /></p>
    <p><label class="question" for="the_address">What is you address?
    </label>
    <input type="text" id="the_address" name="the_address"
            placeholder="Enter your address."
            size="50" required /></p>
    <p><label class="question" for="the_email">What is your e-mail address?
    </label>
   <input type="email" id="the_email" name="the_email"
          placeholder="Please use a real one!"
          size="50" required /></p>
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset>
   <legend>Personal Choices</legend>
   <p><span class="question">Please check all your favorite foods:</span>
   </br>

   <input type="checkbox" id="food_one" name="some_statements[]"
          value="Buffalo Wings" />
   <label for="food_one">Buffalo Wings</label><br/>
   <input type="checkbox" id="food_two" name="some_statements[]"
          value="Enchiladas" />
   <label for="food_two">Enchiladas</label><br/>
   <input type="checkbox" id="food_three" name="some_statements[]"
          value="Hamburgers" />
   <label for="food_three">Hamburgers</label><br/>
   <input type="checkbox" id="food_four" name="some_statements[]"
          value="Spaghetti" />
   <label for="food_four">Spaghetti</label></p>

   <p><span class="question">Select your favorite online store:</span><br/>
   <input type="radio" id="the_amazon" name="online_store"
          value="amazon" />
   <label for="the_amazon"><a href="http://www.amazon.com"        target="_blank">Amazon</label><br/></a>
   <input type="radio" id="bestbuy_electronics" name="online_store"
          value="bestbuy" />
   <label for="bestbuy_electronics"><a href="http:www.bestbuy.com" target="_blank">BestBuy</label><br/></a>
   <input type="radio" id="frys_electronics" name="online_store"
          value="frys" />
   <label for="frys_electronics"><a href="http:www.frys.com" target="_blank">Frys Electronics</label><br/></a>
   </p>
   <p><label for="my_band"><span class="question">Who's your favorite band/ artist?</span></label><br/>
    <select id="my_band" name="my_band" size="4" multiple>
          <option value="The Chi-Lites">The Chi-Lites</option>
          <option value="Michael Buble">Michael Buble</option>
          <option value="Frank Ocean">Frank Ocean</option>
          <option value="Labrinth">Labrinth</option>
    </select>
 </p>
 </fieldset>
 <div id="buttons">
 <input type="submit" value="Click Here to Submit" onclick="display();" />   
  or
 <input type="reset" value="Erase and Start Over" />
 </div>
 </form>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you prevented the default submit functionality?

Try:

```
function display(e) {
//To stop the submit
e.preventDefault();
...
Do your Stuff
...
//Continue the submit
FORM.submit();
}
```

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. It did the same thing.